# Adding picture boxes to a form from a thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, invoke

I'm trying to create picture boxes in a for loop and then adding them to my main form. I create the picture boxes in another thread to decrease the loading time but my application keeps crashing over and over again.

I changed the code 10 times, the actual version looks like this.

```
Private letters() As PictureBox

Private Sub loadLetters()
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    letters = New PictureBox() {}
    For value As Integer = 0 To 7
        letters(value).Image = ImageList1.Images(value + 8)
        letters(value).Name = "picLetter_" & value + 8
        letters(value).Location = New Point(0, j)
        letters(value).Size = New Size(100, 100)
        letters(value).Visible = True
        j = j + 100

        Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf loadLetters))
    Next
End Sub
```

Another attempt of mine brought me to this:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim d As New updateMain(AddressOf loadLetters)
    Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {letters(value)})
Else
    Me.Controls.Add(letters(value))
End If

Private Delegate Sub updateMain(ByVal picture As PictureBox)
```

How can I add picture boxes to the main form from another thread?

Comment: You can't create controls on a non-UI thread. All UI elements must be created on the UI thread otherwise you get errors. The only thing you can do on a background thread is non-UI processing or loading of data. Why are you trying to create them on a background thread?

Comment: @Enigmativity : You are incorrect. I just tested his and my code (after a few initialization corrections on his end) and it's working perfectly fine from another thread (I'm using .NET 4.0). As they're added as variables to an array, the array is accessible from any thread due to that they're not added (nor used) in any container yet.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Sorry, you can create as many UI elements as you like from a non-UI thread so long as you don't attach them to a displayed UI container.

Answer (score 0):

You keep invoking the same method, meaning each time you invoke you are trying to create eight additional picture boxes. The constant and continuous invocation eventually results in a `StackOverflow` exception, due to that you're trying to create an infinite amount of picture boxes.

You have to create a separate method for adding the picture boxes *only*, let your main method create them and the separate method add them to the form.

```
Private Delegate Sub AddPictureBoxDelegate(ByRef PBox As PictureBox)
'ByRef is better to use when not creating a copy of the PictureBox (and when you're not going to modify it as a separate one).

Private Sub AddPictureBox(ByRef PBox As PictureBox)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then 'Invocation is required.
        'Call the method again, using invocation.
        Me.Invoke(New AddPictureBoxDelegate(AddressOf AddPictureBox), PBox)
    Else 'No (further) invocation required.
        Me.Controls.Add(PBox)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, in your thread you just call:

```
AddPictureBox(letters(value))
```

And everything should work as expected.

Comment: May the downvoter care to explain? Or is it due to the comment on the question?

Comment: Calling `.Invoke` to add an a UI element that has been created on a non-UI thread is just asking for trouble. UI elements need to be created on the UI thread so this is providing poor advice. The OP may find that this superficially succeeds, but there will be some operation that will cause it to fall over. Also, there is absolutely no need to have this function call in arguments `ByRef`. And finally there must be some reason that the OP thinks that creating UI elements on another thread is a good ideal. I think it would be worth determining that before providing an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity : According to his post he wants to (or at least as I understand it) "decrease loading time". I know creating/handling controls via different threads is a bad idea, but as I've tested it and it works with no errors, I'd say there's no problem in this context. The picture boxes are created in memory and bound to a variable. They're not used any more in that thread after that. This is the same reason you can read/modify integers, strings, etc., via multiple threads as they're not bound specifically to that thread.

Comment: I used his and mine code to create picture boxes via another thread and add them to a form. Not even the immediate window lists anything.

Comment: When creating a control the following occurs - `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded();` which, if there isn't a synchronization context on the thread, calls `new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext()` which sets `DestinationThread = Thread.CurrentThread;`. So the creation of a control on a non-UI thread causes that control to create a new synchronization context and hold a reference to the current thread which then is likely to end. This is a bad thing to do - even if it seems to work.

Comment: @VisualVincent Currently I am in office and don't have the time to test this. I got myself a Virus and forgot to save my little project about the picture boxes. Damn! ... I will try it as soon as I have time for it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MatthisKohli : No problem. But just remember what Enigmativity says, it is not really safe to create controls on another thread even if it may work.